# Regex find string between characters if left OR right side have at least five characters

Tags: regex

I need to find a string, a dash `-`, between other characters of the alphabet `[A-Za-z]`:

1. if there are more than 5 other characters on the right **OR** (inclusive OR) the left side of the `-`
2. **AND** if there are at least 2 other characters on **both** sides.

I need to use this regex in TexStudio, but I don't which regex implementation is used.

What I've tried so far:

```
[A-Za-z]{2,}[-][A-Za-z]{2,}
```

but this only checks for the second condition of at least 2 characters on both side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternation:

```sh
[A-Za-z]{5}-[A-Za-z]{2}|[A-Za-z]{2}-[A-Za-z]{5}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J8ol8B/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[A-Za-z]{5}-[A-Za-z]{2}`: Match a hyphen with at least 5 letters before and 2 letters after
- `|`: OR
- `[A-Za-z]{2}-[A-Za-z]{5}`: Match a hyphen with at least 2 letters before and 5 letters after

Answer (score 1):

You could match 2-4 chars on the left and 5 or more on the right, or the other way around.

```
\b(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,4}-[a-zA-Z]{5,}|[a-zA-Z]{5,}-[a-zA-Z]{2,4})\b
```

*Explanation*

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `[a-zA-Z]{2,4}-[a-zA-Z]{5,}` Match 2-4 chars a-z `-` and 5 or more chars a-z
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-zA-Z]{5,}-[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` The other way around
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4VMJPA/1)

Comment: Thanks! But I also want to include all sequences with more than 4 characters, as in @anubhava 's answer.